# producing a continuous sound using a timer

Tags: frequency, timer, sound

I'm looking to produce a pure sound on one frequency to be played via a timer to come on at intervals over a six week period. this is for an undergrad dissertation. would an arduino work and could it be fitted to a timer that would turn the sound on remotely? with thanks

Comment: `would an arduino work` : Yes. `could it be fitted to a timer that would turn the sound on remotely`: Yes. You need to ask more specific questions if you hope to get more detailed answers. Simply prefacing this with "How would I ..." would be too broad.

Comment: If a "square wave sound" is sufficient the arduino will be suitable, but "one frequency" sounds like you might want to produce a sine wave. Does "remotely" mean that you want to trigger the sound wirelessly or just using any interface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have some design decisions to make:

**Sleep or no sleep**

You need to decide if you want the Arduino in those 6 weeks to sleep (using less power), or be fully active all the time. The latter is simpler, but it will use some current during those 6 weeks, to be active for a short time.

**Timer**

Different possibilities:

1. You can use a timer, however, I doubt if the timer can handle a long period of 6 weeks. In case you want to sleep, you need to store a counter each time the timer elapses and store it in EEPROM in case you want to have the Arduino in sleep mode, or in a variable when you do not want the Arduino to sleep.
2. Alternatively, you can use a RTC to set an alarm, and use the alarm to either wake up the Arduino (using a GPIO pin to be HIGH/LOW), or activate a function or timer.
3. Also instead of the timer, you can use a big delay (sleep function), but only if you want the Arduino to never sleep.

Check if the accuracy is enough in all cases.

**Buzzer**

For the buzzer, you can easily use an external component. There are plenty of examples how to control this using a frequency and time.